# AngularJS use image/icon as filter option

Tags: angularjs, html, css

I have to filter a gallery by clicking on icons, i.e. the male icon should filter only male images (as the dropdown above does) and the same for the females.

so the dropdown shows what i'm trying to do with the icons, but the icons themselves don't work... what am I missing? Thanks a lot for your help!!

```js
var galleryApp = angular.module('galleryApp', []);

galleryApp.controller('galleryController', function galleryController($scope) {
 $scope.images = [
 {
 "source"  : "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/jeremiah-wilson-1.jpg",
 "altText"  : "Person 1",
 "type"  : "female, all" 
 },
 {
 "source"  : "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/jeremiah-wilson-2.jpg",
 "altText"  : "Person 2",
 "type"  : "malex, all" 
 },
 {
 "source"  : "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/jeremiah-wilson-3.jpg",
 "altText"  : "Person 3",
 "type"  : "malex, all" 
 },
 {
 "source"  : "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/jeremiah-wilson-4.jpg",
 "altText"  : "Person 4",
 "type"  : "malex, all" 
 },
 {
 "source"  : "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/jeremiah-wilson-5.jpg",
 "altText"  : "Person 5",
 "type"  : "female, all" 
 }
];

});
```

```css
body { margin: 0; background: #333; }
#mainGallery { 
  padding: .5vw;
  font-size: 0;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap; 
  flex-flow: row wrap; 
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
}
#mainGallery .imgBlock { 
  -webkit-box-flex: auto;
  -ms-flex: auto;
  flex: auto; 
  width: 200px; 
  margin: .5vw; 
}

#mainGallery .imgBlock img { 
  width: 100%; 
  height: auto;
}
#seperator {
 width: 100%;
 height: 1px;
 display: block;
}
.search {
 background: #222;
 border: 1px solid black;
 width: 500px; 
 padding: 10px 0;
 margin: .5vw auto .5vw auto;
 -moz-border-radius: 10px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
 border-radius: 10px;
}
.dropdown {
 margin-left: 15px;
}
.filterImageWrapper {
 position: relative;
 width: 470px;
 overflow: hidden; 
 margin: 15px;
}
.filterImage {
 width: 470px;
 -moz-border-radius: 4px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
 border-radius: 4px; 
 -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
 transform:translateX(0);
 -webkit-transition: all 1s;
 transition: all 1s;
}
#overlayFilter {
 opacity:0;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 100;
 width: 470px; 
 -webkit-transition:all 1s;
 transition:all 1s;
}
#overlayFilter.overlayOpacity {
 opacity: 1; 
}
#filterBar {
 width: 100%;
 height: 60px;
 background: #666; 
 margin: .5vw;
 -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
 border-radius: 7px;
 border: 1px solid black;
}
.selectedFarbig {
 -webkit-transform: scale(4,4) translate(-40px, 50px);
 transform: scale(4,4) translate(-40px, 50px);
}
.galleryItems {
 -webkit-filter: grayscale(.9) sepia(.3);
 filter: grayscale(.9) sepia(.3);
 -moz-border-radius: 4px; 
 -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
 border-radius: 4px;
 webkit-transition: all .4s;
 transition: all .4s;
}
.galleryItems:hover {
 -webkit-filter: grayscale(.1) sepia(.8); 
}
#filterBar input:first-child {
 height: 50px; 
}
#filterBar input:nth-child(2) {
 height: 50px; 
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  #mainGallery .imgBlock { margin: 0; }
  #mainGallery { padding: 0; }
  
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="galleryApp">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Filter Gallery</title>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="controllers.js"></script>
<link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

<div ng-controller = "galleryController" id="mainGallery">

 <div class="search">
             
        <label class="dropdown">
         <select id="selection" ng-model="query">
             <option value="all">All</option>
             <option value="malex">Male</option>
             <option value="female">Female</option>
            </select>
        </label>
        
    
    <div id="filterBar">
     <input ng-model="query" type="image" src="http://findicons.com/files/icons/438/dating/256/male.png" name="malex" value="malex">   
        <input ng-model="query" type="image" src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-productivity-line-art-2/128/sex-female-512.png" name="female" value="female">     
    </div> 
    <div id="seperator"></div>
 
    <div class="imgBlock" ng-repeat="item in images | filter: query | orderBy: order">
        <!-- images placed inside block elements to deal with a Firefox rendering bug affecting  scaled flexbox images -->
            <img class="galleryItems" src="{{item.source}}" alt="{{item.altText}}" title="{{item.altText}}">
          
        </div>
        
    </div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `input` with type="image" is a [graphical submit button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/image), it doesn't have a meaningful `value` attribute, so that's probably it doesn't really work. Try to simply replace your inputs with something like

```
<img class="imgButton" src="http://findicons.com/files/icons/438/dating/256/male.png" name="malex" ng-click="query = 'malex'" />
<img class="imgButton" src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-productivity-line-art-2/128/sex-female-512.png" name="female" ng-click="query = 'female'" />
```

See updated code:

```js
var galleryApp = angular.module('galleryApp', []);

galleryApp.controller('galleryController', function galleryController($scope) {
 $scope.images = [
 {
 "source"  : "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/jeremiah-wilson-1.jpg",
 "altText"  : "Person 1",
 "type"  : "female, all" 
 },
 {
 "source"  : "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/jeremiah-wilson-2.jpg",
 "altText"  : "Person 2",
 "type"  : "malex, all" 
 },
 {
 "source"  : "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/jeremiah-wilson-3.jpg",
 "altText"  : "Person 3",
 "type"  : "malex, all" 
 },
 {
 "source"  : "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/jeremiah-wilson-4.jpg",
 "altText"  : "Person 4",
 "type"  : "malex, all" 
 },
 {
 "source"  : "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/jeremiah-wilson-5.jpg",
 "altText"  : "Person 5",
 "type"  : "female, all" 
 }
];

});
```

```css
body { margin: 0; background: #333; }
#mainGallery { 
  padding: .5vw;
  font-size: 0;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap; 
  flex-flow: row wrap; 
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
}
#mainGallery .imgBlock { 
  -webkit-box-flex: auto;
  -ms-flex: auto;
  flex: auto; 
  width: 200px; 
  margin: .5vw; 
}

#mainGallery .imgBlock img { 
  width: 100%; 
  height: auto;
}
#seperator {
 width: 100%;
 height: 1px;
 display: block;
}
.search {
 background: #222;
 border: 1px solid black;
 width: 500px; 
 padding: 10px 0;
 margin: .5vw auto .5vw auto;
 -moz-border-radius: 10px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
 border-radius: 10px;
}
.dropdown {
 margin-left: 15px;
}
.filterImageWrapper {
 position: relative;
 width: 470px;
 overflow: hidden; 
 margin: 15px;
}
.filterImage {
 width: 470px;
 -moz-border-radius: 4px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
 border-radius: 4px; 
 -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
 transform:translateX(0);
 -webkit-transition: all 1s;
 transition: all 1s;
}
#overlayFilter {
 opacity:0;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 100;
 width: 470px; 
 -webkit-transition:all 1s;
 transition:all 1s;
}
#overlayFilter.overlayOpacity {
 opacity: 1; 
}
#filterBar {
 width: 100%;
 height: 60px;
 background: #666; 
 margin: .5vw;
 -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
 border-radius: 7px;
 border: 1px solid black;
}
.selectedFarbig {
 -webkit-transform: scale(4,4) translate(-40px, 50px);
 transform: scale(4,4) translate(-40px, 50px);
}
.galleryItems {
 -webkit-filter: grayscale(.9) sepia(.3);
 filter: grayscale(.9) sepia(.3);
 -moz-border-radius: 4px; 
 -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
 border-radius: 4px;
 webkit-transition: all .4s;
 transition: all .4s;
}
.galleryItems:hover {
 -webkit-filter: grayscale(.1) sepia(.8); 
}
#filterBar input:first-child {
 height: 50px; 
}
#filterBar input:nth-child(2) {
 height: 50px; 
}
.imgButton {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  #mainGallery .imgBlock { margin: 0; }
  #mainGallery { padding: 0; }
  
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="galleryApp">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Filter Gallery</title>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="controllers.js"></script>
<link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

<div ng-controller = "galleryController" id="mainGallery">

 <div class="search">
             
        <label class="dropdown">
         <select id="selection" ng-model="query">
             <option value="all">All</option>
             <option value="malex">Male</option>
             <option value="female">Female</option>
            </select>
        </label>
        
    
    <div id="filterBar">
<img class="imgButton" src="http://findicons.com/files/icons/438/dating/256/male.png" name="malex" ng-click="query = 'malex'" />
<img class="imgButton" src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-productivity-line-art-2/128/sex-female-512.png" name="female" ng-click="query = 'female'" />   
    </div> 
    <div id="seperator"></div>
 
    <div class="imgBlock" ng-repeat="item in images | filter: query | orderBy: order">
        <!-- images placed inside block elements to deal with a Firefox rendering bug affecting  scaled flexbox images -->
            <img class="galleryItems" src="{{item.source}}" alt="{{item.altText}}" title="{{item.altText}}">
          
        </div>
        
    </div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Ollie Is there any possibility to add remove class for `imgBlock` when click filter.